# DLCOBJ not releasing the file

Tags: rpgle

maybe someone can help - I have a CL program where I perform ALCOBJ to a file, then call  RPG program and then perform in the CL DLCOBJ. The file is not releasing. Thanks

it's a pf file, In the CL program I perform ALCOBJ on the file, clean the file, call the RPG program where I write to the file in SQL (there is no opening and closing of the file), it ends with *INLR. there is no OVR.

CL:

```
ALCOBJ OBJ((LIB/FILE *FILE *EXCL)) SCOPE(*JOB) 
CALL PGM(PROGRAM) 
DLCOBJ OBJ((FILE *FILE *EXCL))
```

RPGLE:

```
DCL-F File Template; 
DCL-DS x Likerec(File); 

 . . .

Exec sql insert into File values(:x); 
ExSr $SendFileExcel;

*INLR = *ON; 
Return;
```

Comment: What type of file is this, (DB, DEV) ? Does the RPG program close the file ? Does it en with *INLR on ? Is there an OVRDBF SHARE(*YES) or the file created with CRTxF SHARE(*YES) ? Can you share some code from both your programs ?

Comment: From you answer below - the DLCOBJ does not qualify the file the same as ALCOBJ, maybe it is not affecting the file you want.

Comment: How does $SendFileExcel work? is it executing a separate program that might be in a different job?

Answer (score 0):

it's a pf file, In the CL program I perform ALCOBJ on the file, clean the file, call the RPG program where I write to the file in SQL (there is no opening and closing of the file), it ends with *INLR. there is no OVR.
CL:
ALCOBJ OBJ((LIB/FILE *FILE *EXCL)) SCOPE(*JOB)
CALL PGM(PROGRAM)
DLCOBJ OBJ((FILE *FILE *EXCL))

RPGLE:

DCL-F File Template;
DCL-DS x Likerec(File);
.
.
.
Exec sql insert into File values(:x);
ExSr $SendFileExcel;

*INLR = *ON;
Return;

Comment: I'd say the lock comes from SQL, maybe the transaction is still open ?

Comment: Please put this information into your original question.  Don't create a separate answer just to add more info.

Comment: and delete this answer